# How to interact with keypad buttons in my application?

Tags: compact-framework

I am developing a Windows CE5.0 application.
That application is to be deployed in a handheld device.
I want my application to print something on pressing a key on the keypad of the device.

Device contains some keys like mobile phone or any other device.
I don't know how to accept a key input in my application or how to interact with keys.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the KeyDown Event.

```
KeyDown += (o, s) =>
            {
                if (s.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                {
                    // do what ever;
                }
            };
```